# javascript: split string and replace values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, replace, mootools

I'm stuck and have a really bad hangover. forgive me, I'd birthday yesterday. how can I **split a string and replace the needed values** by a simple, stupid javascript function (KISS)?

example:

```
var myvar = "John Doe needs %specialcharDD2% cookies a %specialcharXYV% !" // String 

...

var result = "John Doe needs 50 cookies a day !" // result
```

any help is welcome! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the code below to loop through the matches within the string -

```
var text = 'John Doe needs %specialchar1% cookies a %specialchar2% !';
var matches = text.match(/%[a-zA-Z0-9]*%/g);
for (i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
   alert(matches[i]);
}
```

You might have to change the regex depending on what you're searching for. You can then substitute the 'alert' code with your desired functionality.

Answer (score 4):

don't know why you want to split up the string, but replace can be done simply like this:

`myvar = myvar.replace("%specialchar1%",total)

myvar = myvar.replace("%specialchar2%",period);`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: thank you ! i can not replace it simply like that (sorry for my bad post), cause i do not know the values inside %xyz% - how can i detect them ?

Comment: but I still don't understand your question, you don't know values of `total` and `period` or you don't know what is between `%` ?

Comment: i've reedited my first post above. i do not know the id of the %specialvarID" and need a function to detect them and recieve the value inside of %%.

Answer (score 3):

```
var txt = "John Doe needs %specialchar1% cookies a %specialchar2% !";
var replacements = [50, "day"];

txt.replace(/%specialchar\d+%/mg, function(findings) { return replacements[findings.match(/\d+/)[0] - 1] })
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively;

```
result = repl(myvar, total, period);

function repl(input) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
        input = input.replace("%specialchar" + i + "%", arguments[i]);
    return input
}

//or for global; input = input.replace(new RegExp("%specialchar" + i + "%", "ig"), arguments[i]);
```

Update for token with any ending;

```
function repl(input) {
    var i = 1, args = arguments;
    return myvar.replace(/(%specialchar\w+%)/g, function() {
        return args[i++];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MooTools has a substitute string extension

```
"Hello {myvariable}".substitute({myvariable: "world"});
```

[MooTools docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/String#String%3asubstitute)